# JMockit: Overriding @Mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I have an internal StreamGobbler class that has 7 methods in it. 
I'm looking for a quick way to mock all the methods by default, but override one method named `getOutput()` (e.g. Partial Mocking).

(full code not shown for clarity)

```
public class StreamGobbler extends Thread
{
    public String getOutput() 
    public void run()
}
```

What I would like is to use something like the @Mocked annotation in combination with MockUp to partially mock the getOutput method, but retain all the "default" mocking code on all the other methods. In the docs on partial mocking, it makes the point that if you use MockUp, all non @Mock methods retain their normal functionality. Sometimes that is great, but that isn't what I want in this case.

This is similar to the question [JMockit: @Mocke and MockUp combination in the same test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769669/jmockit-mocke-and-mockup-combination-in-the-same-test), but I can't get away with just looking at method counts.

If I have a test setup like this:

```
@Test
public void execute(@Mocked StreamGobbler sg)
{
    new MockUp<StreamGobbler>()
    {
        String type = null;

        @Mock
        void $init(String type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Mock
        String getOutput()
        {
            if ("OUTPUT".equals(type))
            {
                return "test output";
            }
            else 
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

I get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class already mocked`

If I try to add the @Override annotation in the MockUp, it doesn't help (and Eclipse complains about it)

What is the best way to handle this? Use a static class outside this test method?

Using JMockit 1.17, and TestNG

In summary, how do I get every method in StreamGobbler mocked (as with @Mocked), but partially override one method (without manually doing it myself inside the MockUp?)

Comment: Could you show what the method to be tested (in `StreamGobbler`) looks like? As it is, I am finding it hard to understand what the question is really about.

Comment: @Rogério, edited question to address your question.

Comment: I still don't see *what* you want to test. Is it the `StreamGobbler#run()` method? Although, the question seems to say that *all* methods should be mocked, including `run` and `getOutput`...

Comment: I want to test some code (not listed) that USES StreamGobbler, so I want to Mock up StreamGobbler. I want to supply a "fake" getOutput() implementation for the test. My code executes external scripts through ProcessBuilder and StreamGobbler is involved. I know what the intended output is from the external process, so I will supply it in the faked out getOutput() method. The code calling getOutput() is what my test is built around.

Comment: Added summary statement to question to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full example code which meets the given constraints:

```
public static class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    public StreamGobbler(String type) {}
    public String getOutput() { return null; }
    @Override public void run() {}
}

public static class TestedClass {
    public String doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        StreamGobbler sg1 = new StreamGobbler("OUTPUT");
        sg1.start();

        StreamGobbler sg2 = new StreamGobbler("ERROR");
        sg2.start();

        sg1.join(5000);
        sg2.join(5000);

        String output1 = sg1.getOutput();
        String output2 = sg2.getOutput();
        return output1 + '|' + output2;
    }
}

@Test
public void useStreamGobbler(@Mocked StreamGobbler sg) throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {{
        new StreamGobbler("OUTPUT").getOutput(); result = "test output";
        new StreamGobbler("ERROR").getOutput(); result = "";
    }};

    String output = new TestedClass().doSomething();

    assertEquals("test output|", output);
}
```

Comment: I get this:

mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing 1 invocation to:
mypkg.StreamGobbler#getOutput()
   on mock instance: mypkg.StreamGobbler@4934ce4a
Caused by: Missing invocations

Comment: Also notice how my MockUp example only returns the hard-coded output when constructed with the "OUTPUT" argument (e.g. stdout). The code I'm testing will also use another instance of StreamGobbler to capture stderr. I don't want any output for that instance. The StreamGobbler objects are instantiated deep inside the method I'm testing.

Comment: The updates help alot. One other complication: My StreamGobbler constructor has an InputStream as an argument. The InputStream in the tested code comes from a Process object. In my test method, I used this:

new StreamGobbler(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]), "ERROR").getOutput(); result="";

getOutput() is returning null instead of the result I'm specifying.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to use `(InputStream)any` in my test method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you are creating an *anonymous subclass* of the [MockUp](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/MockUp.html) class, using the @Override annotation would certainly be inappropriate. Those methods that you are providing do not belong to the MockUp class, but the generic you are providing.

Later on during runtime, (through some impressive process (based on what I read [here](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Mocked.html), I'm assuming AOP)) the instance you create in this class will then use your provided method signatures instead of its own.

After reading the API on the [Mock](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Mock.html) class more thoroughly as well as getting some information from [JMockit's Getting Started](http://jmockit.org/gettingStarted.html#record) page, I think you're issue lies in a different area entirely. If you have other test methods, they will be interfering with this method.

The error you are getting is saying: "There is already an instance of MockUp declared for the type *StreamGobbler*, and by calling the **Mocked** annotation in this test method's parameters *and* attempting to declare another instance of MockUp with the same generic, you are violating a JMockit stipulation."
I would check to see if you are creating an actual MockUp of StreamGobbler outside of the test method and if so (1) if you want to use it, don't redeclare another instance of MockUp in the method but continue to use the Mocked annotation or (2) if you do not want to use it and you want to re-declare a new instance of MockUp wrapping StreamGobbler, do not use the Mocked annotation in the test method's parameters but keep the MockUp instantiation.

Comment: Using TestNG, and JMockit, not Mockito